# Android selection issue in ListView

Tags: android, listview, selection

I have a ListView (set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)
I have a SimpleCursorAdapter who fill my ListView. Now i work on selection.

```
serviceListView.setAdapter(
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.service_listitem, cursor, new String[] { "name" }, new int[] { R.id.service_name }) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View renderer = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (position == newSelectedPosition) {
                renderer.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.list_view_layer_list);
            } else {
                renderer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
            return renderer;
        }
    }
);
```

So i want when i select a row my layout to be applied. This works fine.
But in some cases when i push for 2-3 secs a row and then drag a little bit and release the row i obtain 2 rows selected.
I try several ways to get ride of the initial selection, overwriting OnTouchListener, OnScrollListener, OnLongClickListener. No results.
Any help is welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quit this implementation. 
I will try to "simulate" ListView by using a ScrollView with TextView-s for each row

Comment: It works just fine. For other users that has the same problem try to replace ListView with a ScrollView filled with TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter after the selection has been changed? That should cause all the rows to be rebound again, and all the views (except for the selected one) to revert back to the transparent background.

Comment: Sorry I would have thought that would work. I can't see how the same position would be bound twice. I'm not sure if calling notifyDataSetChanged when your finger is lifted off the screen would help. Maybe try adding some logs to the selected function and the bind function might help you see what is going on.